# How to extract time in "HH:MM" format from index?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe as shown below:

[image]

This dataframe has index as datetime format i want to extract only "HH:MM" part of it.

I tried `pd.DatetimeIndex(dfl.iloc[looppar]).hour`

which, does not return values as intended.
In above code looppar indicates row number, say for first row i want to extract only time in format "09:18".

Comment: pd.DatetimeIndex(dfl.iloc[looppar]).strftime("%H:%M")

Comment: this command return following output: "Index(['00:00', '00:00'], dtype='object', name=2021-08-07 09:18:55)". I gave looppar as 0, and with that i need just "09:18" as a string, could you please helps me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want index list with hour:minute

```
df1.index.strftime("%H:%M").tolist()
```

if you want only one

```
df1.index.strftime("%H:%M")[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# create sample dataframe
idx = pd.date_range('2021-07-24 09:28:01', periods=3, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'idx': idx, 'val': np.random.randn(len(idx)) })
df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['idx']), inplace=True, drop=True)

# apply function to index column to create new column with H:M
df['hm'] = df.index.map(lambda i: i.strftime('%H:%M'))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                                              val    hm
idx                                                    
2015-02-24 09:28:01 2015-02-24 09:28:01 -0.344819  09:28
2015-02-24 10:28:01 2015-02-24 10:28:01 -1.616330  10:28
2015-02-24 11:28:01 2015-02-24 11:28:01  1.711378  11:28
```